Change index of C++ range based for loop using views::enumerate
In C++, using a range based for loop, I can use views::enumerate to obtain both the value and the index of a vector.
I'm trying to decrease the index so that in the next iteration the loop will run again with the same index:
#include <ranges>

class Solution {
public:
    string restoreString(string s, vector<int>& indices) {
        for (const auto &[i, index] : views::enumerate(indices))
        {
            if (index == i)    continue;

            swap(s[i], s[index]);
            swap(indices[i], indices[index]);

            long& nci = const_cast<long&>(i);
            --nci;
        }

        return s;
    }
};

If I try to access i as a pointer it requires to use const, so I can't change i directly, so I tried to use const_cast, but even then the value of i is not changed in the next loop.
Is it possible to change the value of the index when using views::enumerate in a C++ range based for loop?

No, write the loop manually. Not everything needs a stdlib abstraction. For extra style points you can embed the index declaration into the for: for (std::size_t i = 0; const auto &index : indices) {...; i++;}.
